# Mouse hovering is not applied on menu-icon, just only on the menu-text

Tags: html, css, sass, angular7

style.scss

```
.appSubMenu {   
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: $fontsize;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.appSubMenu:hover {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: $fontsize;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    color:#508be4!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.appSubMenu img.chevDownTorq:hover {
    content:url("./assets/icons/cheveron_down_hovered.svg")!important;   
}
```

app.comp.html

```
  <a *ngIf="item.value.length!=0" href="#" class="nav-link appSubMenu"
    data-toggle="dropdown" id="{{i}}" > my menu <img class = "chevDownTorq" src="assets/icons/chevron_down_torq.png"/>
  </a>
```

On clicking the chevron my entire text and the chevron is changed to color #508be4, but on clicking the text(my menu) only my text color changes and chevron remains black. What can i do here to have a better functionality?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want on `.appSubMenu:hover` styling to take place, so instead of `.appSubMenu img.chevDownTorq:hover` do `.appSubMenu:hover img.chevDownTorq`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have SCSS, you could use the following (moving your rules meant for the icon/chevron inside the `.appSubMenu:hover`):

```
.appSubMenu {   
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: $fontsize;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.appSubMenu:hover {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: $fontsize;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    color:#508be4!important;
    cursor: pointer;

    img.chevDownTorq {
        content:url("./assets/icons/cheveron_down_hovered.svg")!important;
    }
}
```